# Is form submitted if <form> tag has no name attribute (and child <input> elements within form do have name attribute?

Tags: html

If I do not specify name attribute within  tag, is everything within form is submitted successfully?

I know that  without name is not submitted in either GET or POST

Comment: Yes, all values of form controls with `[name]` are submitted with one exception: `<output>` . If you want to send the value of an `<output>` just copy it over to a `<input type='hidden'>`. Also, if you have a group of radio buttons that have the same `[name]` -- only the value of the selected radio button is submitted.

Comment: check by answer bro i will help u for sure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Submitting a `<form>`

> *"Is form submitted if  tag has no name attribute (and child  elements within form do have name attribute?"*

- Yes, all values of form controls<sup>1</sup> with a `[name]` and nested within a `<form>`<sup>2</sup> tag are submitted with one exception: `<output>`. If you want to send the value of an `<output>` just copy it over to a `<input type='hidden'>`.
- Forms do not require a `[name]` attribute to send values of its children tags or for itself (since forms actually don't have value attributes).
- If you have a group of radio buttons that have the same `[name]` -- only the value of the selected radio button is submitted.
- There is a default behavior the `<button>` tag has when nested within a form it will act as a `<input type="submit">`. So remember to add `type="button"` to `<button>`s that are just buttons to trigger a click event instead of a submit event.
- If focus is set within a form and the <kbd>enter</kbd> (<kbd>return</kbd> for Macs) key is clicked also triggers a submit event.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Children tags of a `<form>` tag that have the `[name]`/value sent during a submission is known as [successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup>If a form control is not a child of a form, an association can be enabled by assigning the control `form="FORMID"`</sup>

---

### Demo

#### `<form>`

- `[action]`: Sends to a live test server
- `[target]`: `[name]` of an iframe that displays the server's response
- `[onchange]`: Whenever the user leaves data on the form -- `<output>` displays the value of the selected radio button and `<output>` assigns the value to the hidden input as well.

```css
#ui {
  width: 300px;
}

#out,
button,
[type=submit] {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form id='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response' onchange='out.value = rad.value; inv.value = out.value; return false'>
  <fieldset id='ui'>
    <legend>Submitting a Form</legend>
    <fieldset>
      <input id='xA' name='rad' type='radio' value='A'> A
      <input id='xB' name='rad' type='radio' value='B'> B
      <input id='xC' name='rad' type='radio' value='C'> C
      <input id='xD' name='rad' type='radio' value='D'> D
      <output id='out' name='out' for='xA xB xC xD inv'></output>
      <input id='inv' name='inv' type='hidden'>
    </fieldset>
    <button>&lt;button&gt;</button>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes form will submit even if it has not no name. check the code below it will explain you.

**Click on the submit button form will submit, even if it does not have name,action etc.**
submit button is enough to submit the form.

> If you dont mention meathod then default submit type is "Get" meathod

```html
<form action='/cloud' meathod="get">
<input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

FYI - use of name attributes on forms are deprecated for id in HTML5. See [the MDN note about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-name).

> The name of the form. In HTML 4, its use is deprecated (id should be used instead). It must be unique among the forms in a document and not just an empty string in HTML 5.

**Edits**:

1. fixed typo from earlier post on mobile that made it seem like I was suggesting `<input>` name attributes are deprecated.
2. Added quote from MDN

Comment: MDN is incorrect, or at least misleading. The name attribute on form elements is not deprecated or obsoleted in either HTML 4 or HTML 5. It's true that the HTML 4 spec encourages the use of id instead, but does not formally deprecate the attribute. HTML 5 does not even do that. [HTML 4's definition of the name attribute on the form element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM).  [HTML 5's definition of the name attribute on the form element](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-name)

Answer (score 0):

yes you have give form method like:

```
<form method="post OR get">
</form>
```

and also give element name because element name used to post the value of that element.